# CPU usage way higher on Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Two phones (Galaxy S8 and Google Pixel) were using around 4% cpu usage on average with my app.

Since updating to Android Oreo on both, CPU usage has surged to 15%-30% on S8 and 30-50% on the Pixel. The same build still only runs at ~4% CPU usage on a Moto G4 that does not have Android 8.

Is there a known CPU usage issue with Android Oreo, or something I should be aware of that has changed that I should reflect in my code or anything?

Specifically, are there gradle changes I might need to make to better support Android Oreo, or other framework changes specific to Android Oreo that would result in such a CPU spike?

Comment: i agree i noticed that two and that is causing my battery to drain really fast ... i just cant figure what is using so much cpu power
id root my phone and install some custom kernel but iam too lasy to install back an official firmware because i need i need to update my phone via ota
update: i disabled some system apps like google and fisabled background activity of a lot of apps including android system lol and it seema like it is working ?! iam using my phone for like an hour now and my battery life is at 90%